# “ValueError: chunksize cannot exceed dimension size” when trying to write xarray to netcdf

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, python-xarray

As per ["ValueError: chunksize cannot exceed dimension size" when trying to write xarray to netcdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39900011/valueerror-chunksize-cannot-exceed-dimension-size-when-trying-to-write-xarray), setting engine to scipy should fix this error. However, this does not play with zlib=True in the encodings. How do I still zip the netCDF, currently I get this error with scipy engine:

```
*** ValueError: unexpected encoding for scipy backend: ['zlib']
```

Comment: This looks like an xarray bug. If you have time, self-contained code for reproducing it would be very helpful in tracking it down:
https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/1225

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SciPy's netCDF reader/writer only supports the netCDF3 format, which does not support in-file compression (a netCDF4 feature). To use `zlib=True` you'll need to write netCDF files using either `engine='netcdf4'` or `engine='h5netcdf'`.